How to correctly use 'document.delete' to delete Firestore data?
I'm new to using Firestore with Swift but I am making progress.
I am currently working on the gym plan creation section, with me just finishing up the views where a user can create their own plan and it saves to the database and views on their 'plans' page.
I am now trying to add a delete button to these plans, but I am not having much luck.
When I try to use the deletePlan function on a button, Xcode does not let me build the active scheme, returning the error:

The compiler is unable to type-check this expression in reasonable time; try breaking up the expression into distinct sub-expressions

This is my PlansViewModel code:
final class PlansViewModel {
    
    static let shared = PlansViewModel()
    private init() { }
    
    //Empty list array that is defined in 'Exercises' Model file:
    @Published var plans = [Plans]()
    
    let plansRef = Firestore.firestore().collection("plans")
    
    
    
    //Function that fetches data items from Firestore to store in empty list array:
    func getData() async throws -> [Plans]{
        
        let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid ?? "" // Construct the expected userID format
        
        //read documents from database
        let snapshot = try await plansRef.whereField("User", isEqualTo: userID).getDocuments()
        
        var plans: [Plans] = []
        
        for document in snapshot.documents {
            //Transform document into the array
            do {
                let plan = try document.data(as: Plans.self)
                plans.append(plan)
            } catch {
                print(String(describing: error))
            }
            
        }
        print(plans)
        return plans
        
    }
    
    // Function to save a new plan to Firestore
    func newPlan(name: String, user: String, exercises: [ExercisesArray]) async throws -> String {
        do {
            let documentRef = try plansRef.addDocument(from: Plans(name: name, user: user, exercises: exercises))
            let documentID = documentRef.documentID
            print("New plan added with ID: \(documentID)")
            return documentID
        } catch {
            print("Error adding new plan: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            throw error
        }
    }
    
    
    func deletePlan(planToDelete: Plans) {
        // Check if planToDelete.id is nil
        guard let documentID = planToDelete.id else {
            print("Error: Document ID is nil")
            return
        }
        
        // Get a reference to the db document to delete
        plansRef.document(documentID).delete { error in
            // Handle error
            if let error = error {
                // Error present
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    // Update UI on main thread
                    print("There was an error whilst deleting plan document: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                }
            } else {
                // No errors
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    // Remove deleted plan from plans array
                    self.plans.removeAll { plan in
                        return plan.id == planToDelete.id
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        
        
        
    }
}

And this is my PlansView code:
@MainActor
final class UserPlansViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published private(set) var plans: [Plans] = []
    
    func getData() async throws {
        self.plans = try await PlansViewModel.shared.getData()
        //print("Fetched plans: \(plans)")
    }
    
}

struct DisplayPlansView{
    
    @ObservedObject private var viewModel = UserPlansViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            LazyVStack {
                ForEach(viewModel.plans, id: \.id) { plan in
                    VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 16) {
                        Text(plan.name)
                            .font(.title2)
                            .bold()
                        Text("Exercises:")
                            .font(.title3)
                            .bold()
                        
                        if let exercises = plan.exercises {
                            ForEach(exercises, id: \.exerciseName) { exercise in
                                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                                    Text(exercise.exerciseName)
                                        .font(.subheadline)
                                        .bold()
                                    
                                    if let sets = exercise.sets {
                                        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                                            ForEach(sets.indices, id: \.self) { index in
                                                let set = sets[index]
                                                HStack {
                                                    Text("Set \(index + 1):")
                                                        .font(.caption)
                                                        .foregroundColor(.gray)
                                                    Spacer()
                                                    Text("\(set.reps) x \(set.weight)KG")
                                                        .font(.caption)
                                                        .foregroundColor(.gray)
                                                    Spacer()
                                                    Text("\(set.rest) Seconds Rest")
                                                        .font(.caption)
                                                        .foregroundColor(.gray)
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    } else {
                                        Text("No sets found")
                                            .font(.caption)
                                            .foregroundColor(.gray)
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        } else {
                            Text("No exercises found")
                                .font(.subheadline)
                                .foregroundColor(.gray)
                        }
                        Divider()
                        
                        Group {
                            HStack(alignment: .center) {
                                Button {
                                    Task {
                                        //try await model.editPlan()
                                    }
                                } label: {
                                    Text("Edit Plan")
                                    Image(systemName: "square.and.pencil")
                                }
                                .bold()
                                .foregroundStyle(.yellow)
                                
                                Divider()
                                    .frame(height: 35)
                                
                                
                                Button(action: {
                                    Task {
                                        viewModel.deletePlan(planToDelete: plan)
                                        //delete plan
                                    }}, label: {
                                        Text("Delete Plan")
                                        Image(systemName: "trash")
                                    })
                                    .bold()
                                    .foregroundStyle(.red)
                            }
                        }
                        
                        Divider()
                    }
                    .padding()
                    .background(Color.gray.opacity(0.1), in: RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 12, style: .continuous))
                }
            }
            .padding()
        }
        .task {
            try? await viewModel.getData()
        }
    }
}

As soon as I comment out the button that uses the deletePlan function, the code runs fine and everything works as desired which means either the deletePlan function, the way it's implemented into the PlansView, or the actual delete button is the problem, right?
I have tried to change variable names and code the function in different ways but nothing seems to work, which is irritating because the addPlan function works just fine, even though that seems more complicated and much more beefy which makes me think the error (as describe earlier) is strange.
